# select: result based on occurrence of explicit value

Tags: mysql, sql

Given is following mysql table:

```
CREATE TABLE fonts
    (`id` int, `fontName` varchar(22), `price` int,`reducedPrice` int,`weight` int)
;

INSERT INTO fonts
    (`id`, `fontName`, `price`,`reducedprice`,`weight`)
VALUES
    (1, 'regular', 50,30,1),
    (2, 'regular-italic', 50,20,1),
    (3, 'medium', 60,30,2),
    (4, 'medium-italic', 50,30,2),
    (5, 'bold', 50,30,3),
    (6, 'bold-italic', 50,30,3),
    (7, 'bold-condensed', 50,30,3),
    (8, 'super', 50,30,4)
;
```

As an example a user chooses following ids: 1,2,3,5,6,7
which would result in following query/result:

```
> select * from fonts where id in(1,2,3,5,6,7);

id  fontName        price       reducedPrice    weight
1   regular         50          30              1
2   regular-italic  50          20              1
3   medium          60          30              2
5   bold            50          30              3
6   bold-italic     50          30              3
7   bold-condensed  50          30              3
```

Is it possible to have a kind of "if statement" in a query to return a new field based on column weight. Where a value occurs more than once reducedPrice should be returned as newPrice else price:

```
id  fontName        price   reducedPrice    weight    newPrice
1   regular         50      30              1         30
2   regular-italic  50      20              1         20
3   medium          60      30              2         60
5   bold            50      30              3         30
6   bold-italic     50      30              3         30
7   bold-condensed  50      30              3         30
```

**Which means ids 1,2,5,6,7 should be reduced but id 3 not as its weight "2" only occurs once**

Please find a fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/73f5db/1
And thanks for your help!

Comment: fiddle link gives http status code 404

Comment: @dr0i: working here see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/73f5db/1

Comment: ah, page not working with my normal browser properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a subquery that gets the number of occurrences of each weight, and join with this. Then you can test the number of occurrences to decide which field to put in `NewPrice`.

```
SELECT f.*, IF(weight_count = 1, Price, ReducedPrice) AS NewPrice
FROM fonts AS f
JOIN (SELECT weight, COUNT(*) AS weight_count
      FROM fonts
      WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7)
      GROUP BY weight) AS w ON f.weight = w.weight
WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7)
```

[Updated fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/73f5db/6)

Answer (score 0):

```
select *,if(occurences>=2,reducedPrice,price) as newPrice from fonts
left join (Select count(id) as occurences, id,weight from fonts
where fonts.id in(1,2,3,5,6,7) group by weight) t on t.weight = fonts.weight
where fonts.id in(1,2,3,5,6,7);
```

The mysql if keyword reference is here:https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if

Edit: Added fiddle, changed to instances as comment requested.
Updated fiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a93ef/14

Comment: But this checks the value of weight? right? I´ve asked for the occurrence. Which means ids 1,2,5,6,7 should be reduced but id 3 not as its weight "2" only occurs once.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.*
              , CASE WHEN y.weight = x.weight THEN x.reducedPrice ELSE x.price END newPrice 
           FROM fonts x 
           LEFT 
           JOIN 
              ( SELECT * FROM fonts WHERE id IN(1,2,3,5,6,7) )y
             ON y.weight = x.weight 
            AND y.id <> x.id  
          WHERE x.id IN(1,2,3,5,6,7)
          ORDER 
             BY id;
```